# IOS/Objective-C: Programatically Change Text of Title for Standard UITabBar item

Tags: ios, uitabbarcontroller

When a user segues to a second VC from within a starting VC that is embedded in a `UITabBarController`, I change the title of the `UITabbarItem` with some code placed in the `viewWillAppear` method of the second view controller.

//Second VC, View WIll Appear

```
UITabBarItem *selectedItem = self.tabBarController.tabBar.selectedItem;
    if (selectedItem) {
        selectedItem.title = @"VoiceMail";
    }
```

This works fine.

When the user returns to the starting view controller, I want to switch the title back.

I tried to do this by placing similar code in the view will appear method of the starting view controller.

Starting VC: ViewWIllAppear

```
UITabBarItem *selectedItem = self.tabBarController.tabBar.selectedItem;
    if (selectedItem) {
        selectedItem.title = @"Phone";
    }
```

But it is having no effect, leaving the title as `Voicemail`.

WOuld appreciate any suggestions on how to change back to initial value.

Thanks for any suggestions.

Comment: Are you certain `selectedItem` still exists when you pop back to the first VC?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Trying to change the "2nd" tab title by referencing `.selectedItem` in your "Starting VC" won't work, because at that point `.selectedItem` ***is*** `StartingVC`.

One approach would be to save a reference to the index of `SecondVC`... then, inside *that* VC, on `viewWillDisappear` you can reset its tab's title:

This is all in `SecondVC`:

```
#import "ChangeSecondViewController.h"

@interface ChangeSecondViewController ()

@property (assign, readwrite) NSInteger myTabIndex;

@end

@implementation ChangeSecondViewController

- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated {
    [super viewWillAppear:animated];
    UITabBarItem *selectedItem = self.tabBarController.tabBar.selectedItem;
    if (selectedItem) {
        selectedItem.title = @"VoiceMail";
    }
}

- (void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated {
    [super viewDidAppear:animated];
    _myTabIndex = self.tabBarController.selectedIndex;
}

- (void)viewWillDisappear:(BOOL)animated {
    [super viewWillDisappear:animated];
    UITabBarItem *myTabItem = [[self.tabBarController.tabBar items] objectAtIndex:_myTabIndex];
    if (myTabItem) {
        myTabItem.title = @"Phone";
    }
}

@end
```